# Can second player still use bombs?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac-rebirth

Did they stop letting the second player (baby) put bombs? I thought it was my remote, I bought a new one and it still won't allow me.

Answer (score 5):

According to [SteamCommunity](https://steamcommunity.com/app/250900/discussions/0/619574421198909093/):

> In the newest patch they made it so player 2 can't place bombs.